# Macro is not copying data validation in the cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have a macro to copy a selection from a sheet and email it as a separate attachment, however it is not copying the data validation that exists in those cells.

In the sheet there is validation that exists in columns AT, AU, AV, AW, and AY. When I run the code below it doesn't copy the validation into the sheet being e-mailed. I need the attachment to have the same validation  in those columns as the original sheet and the same formatting.

```
Sub send_email()
Dim Data, Dict As Object, Id As String, File As String, i As Long
Set Dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
With Cells(1).CurrentRegion
    Data = .Value
    For i = 2 To UBound(Data)
        If Not Dict.exists(Data(i, 59)) Then
            Id = Data(i, 58)
            File = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Id & " - PCP" & ".xlsx"
            Dict.Add Data(i, 59), 1
            .AutoFilter 59, Data(i, 59)
            .SpecialCells(12).Copy Sheets.Add.Cells(1)
            With ActiveSheet
                .Copy
                With ActiveWorkbook
                    .ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1"
                    .SaveAs File
                    .Close
                End With
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False: .Delete: Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End With
            With CreateObject("Outlook.Application").CreateItem(0)
                .display
                .To = Data(i, 59)
                .Subject = "Work Assignment for Today"
                .HTMLBody = "Good Morning " & "<br><br>" & "Please find attached your work assignment for the day" & .HTMLBody
                .Attachments.Add File
                .display '! Change to Send after testing
            End With
            Kill File
            .AutoFilter
        End If
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure that the data validation is not being copied into your new workbook file? Data validation rules are only triggered when a user attempts to enter data into a cell. See: this question from Stack Overflow - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179910/null-validation-in-excel-column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using the below code.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Array(.Name, "Disp")).Copy
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).